# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while running Spark Java program

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am trying the following program :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;


public class SparkMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logFile = "~/useful/json.json    "; // Should be some file on your system
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

        long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
        }).count();

        long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
        }).count();

        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
    }
}
```

The pom.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>artid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I am using intellij and when I run debug on the main function, I get the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sudeep/spark/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sudeep/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.12/slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sudeep/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/07/06 00:55:57 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.2
16/07/06 00:55:57 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/06 00:55:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sudeep
16/07/06 00:55:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sudeep
16/07/06 00:55:58 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(sudeep); users with modify permissions: Set(sudeep)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.timeStringAsSec(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeStringAsSeconds(Utils.scala:993)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$.apply(RpcTimeout.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.lookupRpcTimeout(RpcUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.<init>(RpcEnv.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:14)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51826', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get "ClassNotFound" inside your IDE you need to confirm this not an IDE glitch. In general, this error happens when the compiled version of Spark is different than the used in run time.

To test that this is not an IDE glitch, simply run your program using just you build tool (`maven run`). If it works then at least you know your `pom` file is correct. If this is the case, then I suggest creating a new project with fresh dependencies. Your IDE may be using an older version of Spark.